# Match the Values from Calculated Variable with Column A and Create a new Column B with all matching rows from Column A in Column B

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on **Python 3.6.4** 
**FYI:** Current Week is 19th

I have created a variable which gives me L26Weeks, Now I have to match these L26W dates with already existing dates in Column A (which Contains L52W dates). The dates which are not matching with Column A need to be named as "**Others**" and remaining should be displayed as dates.

Here is the code what I wrote

```
def main(self):
    a = self['Week_No']
    b = self['L26W']
    result = 'Others'
    for row in a:
        # print(type(row))
        for row2 in b:
            if row2 == row:
                return row
    return result
final['Test'] = final.apply(main, axis =1)
```

I am getting this error:

[image: Error]

You can get the dataset from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y-Wmdn-r8R7Iy5McacfF79AEdZsf7do8)

Comment: In my opinion the `self['L26W']` gives a float number which is not iterable. You should print `b` variable before your `for` loop and check what type of variable you have.

Comment: Appreciate your answer one error has been resolved. Now, in the final result I am directly getting L26W (26 rows only) but In column B I want to show these L26W matching with **Week_New** (Column A)